# Sortable and draggable behavior on list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm coming here because I'm having trouble doing something with jQuery UI's sortable/draggable/droppable.

I'm trying to do something like iTunes playlist (when you change the order of tracklist or move a track to another playlist)
The idea is that I have a list of tracks (in a ) and I want this list to be sortable, and that's the easy part. Indeed I also have a second list (of playlist) and I want tracks to be draggable to those "playlist" items to do something.

Here's an exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/MSGhf/1/

(the sortable is working exactly as I want it, the black line is just a `<div class="plholder"></div>`)

But when you start dragging a track, sortable works fine. But when you move the track out of the draggable, the new order stays, and so dragging tracks on playlist potentialy change the track list order too, which is a problem.

So I don't know how to block the sortable when a track leaves it.

If you have any idea :)

Thanks !

Comment: Hm. If I understand your requirement correctly, Firefox is working this way already. What browser appears to be giving you grief?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, ok, I see what's happening. Here's what you want to do (working example, here: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/L3CF8/1/)

```
    $(".droppable").droppable({
        tolerance: "pointer",
        drop:function(){
            // You need to tell your sortable to cancel 
            // the last drag/drop interaction
            $("ul").sortable("cancel");
            alert("Do something on drop ...");   
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah ! That's exactly what I wanted ! Tanks a lot :) And what if I want to cancel the sortable when user release the track out of the sortable?

Comment: I've been looking at that, and it seems a bit trickier. I think what you'd have to do is track the mouse position, see if it is still over your original sortable object, and use the out: event to test whether you're still over the original sortable, cancelling if it's outside. I haven't nailed down the specifics, however, and don't have time to go much further into this, but you can see what I've attempted to do, here: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/L3CF8/5/

Comment: Ok I totally get it, that's exactly the idea I had but I didn't knew how to start. That will definitively help a lot, by now I think I can finish by my self. Thank you very much mori57, you made my day :)